# How to push my JMeter project to Github and run it via pipeline from Jenkins

Tags: jmeter, jenkins, git, jenkins-pipeline

I have a `.jmx` file and I run it in `NON-GUI` mode on my local machine.

I'd like to push my project to `Github` and run it via pipeline from `Jenkins`.

How can I do that?

1. Do I need to push the whole `JMeter` folder to `Github` in order to have the ability to run my `JMeter` test from `Jenkins`?
2. What do I need to specify in the pipeline script?

Comment: You will get better answers on SO--nothing about this is testing-specific even though JMeter is a testing tool.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need 3 things in order to run JMeter test in Jenkins:

1. JMeter .jmx script itself
2. [Java Runtime](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html)
3. JMeter

If you have JMeter installed on the machine the minimal [pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) would look like:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'your_branch', credentialsId: 'your_credentials', url: 'your_git_url'

            }
        }
    }
    stage('Run JMeter Test') {
        steps {
            dir('your_project_folder') {
                sh '/path/to/jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Mind that `sh` is applicable for Linux/Unix/MacOSX systems, if your Jenkins master or slave is running Windows - change it to `bat`

See [How to Run a JMeter Test with Jenkins 2.0 Pipelines and GitHub](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-jmeter-test-jenkins-20-pipelines-and-github) article for detailed setup instructions if needed.

Couple more useful links:

- You might want to use [JMeter Maven plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) in order to get automatic dependencies management, the chance that you have Maven installed in Jenkins is much higher than JMeter and Maven can download and configure JMeter automatically
- You might also want to use [Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin) which can publish test results and performance trends reports to your build dashboard.

Comment: thanks for your reply. What should I put on ```stage('Run JMeter Test')``` in the pipeline script in the case when my project isn't on local but is on Git?

Comment: Stage `Checkout` will pull your project from Git into Jenkins workspace

Comment: @KonstantinV this is fairly basic stuff, you should probably best start by learning the basics of Jenkins. There's another option (that I haven't tried) [using the performance-plugin](http://jenkinsci.github.io/performance-plugin/RunTests.html)